# how to create multiple relationships in a single cypher statement

Tags: neo4j

I must create a set of relationships, all having the same source and type, like in the following sample:

```
create (_1)-[:`typ`]->(:`x` {`name`:"Mark"})
create (_1)-[:`typ`]->(:`y` {`name`:"Jane"})
create (_1)-[:`typ`]->(:`z` {`name`:"John"})
...
```

I'd like to have a shorten way to write those statements, like following attempt?

```
create (_1)-[:`typ`]->[(:`x` {`name`:"Mark"}),
                       (:`y` {`name`:"Jane"}),
                       (:`z` {`name`:"John"})]
```

Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Paolo

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in a performant and easy way by this pattern:

```
{batch: [
{from:"alice@example.com",to:"bob@example.com",properties:{since:2012}},
{from:"alice@example.com",to:"charlie@example.com",properties:{since:2016}}]}
UNWIND {batch} as row

MATCH (from:Label {row.from})
MATCH (to:Label {row.to})
CREATE/MERGE (from)-[rel:KNOWS]->(to)
(ON CREATE) SET rel += row.properties
```

Taken with thanks from [5 Tips & Tricks for Fast Batched Updates of Graph Structures with Neo4j and Cypher](https://medium.com/neo4j/5-tips-tricks-for-fast-batched-updates-of-graph-structures-with-neo4j-and-cypher-73c7f693c8cc) by @MichaelHunger.